# datetime groupby/resample month and day across different years (drop the year)

Tags: python, date, pandas, datetime

I have looked at the resample/Timegrouper functionality in Pandas.  However, I'm trying to figure out how to use it for this specific case.  I want to do a seasonal analysis across a financial asset - let's say S&P 500.  I want to know how the asset performs between any two custom dates on average across many years.

Example:  If I have a 10 year history of daily changes of S&P 500 and I pick the date range between March 13th and March 23rd, then I want to know the average change for each date in my range across the last 10 years - i.e. average change on 3/13 each year for the last 10 years, and then for 3/14, 3/15 and so on until 3/23.  This means I need to groupby month and day and do an average of values across different years.

I can probably do this by creating 3 different columns for year, month, and day and then grouping by two of them, but I wonder if there are more elegant ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  It turned out to be pretty simple and I was just being dumb.

```
x.groupby([x.index.month, x.index.day], as_index=True).mean()
```

where x is a pandas series in my case (but I suppose could also be a dataframe?).  This will return a multi-index series which is ok in my case, but if it's not in your case then you can manipulate it to drop a level or turn the index into new columns