# Why does pandas dayofyear return 366 rows after I've removed the leap days?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains 11 years' worth of max and min temperature data (2005 to 2015). I am trying to find the highest and lowest temperature for each day of the year over the 10 year period .

I removed the 2 leap days from the data, i.e. 2008-02-29 and 2012-02-29, but when I apply dayofyear to the data, it returns 366 rows and I can't work out why.

I've broken down the steps and tested each part. The leap day dates are definitely not in the dataframe when I apply dayofyear

After I've removed the leap days and checked using this:
   `dfmax['2008-02-26':'2008-03-02']`

29th Feb is not there.

The next step is to aggregate the date by day of year to get highest temp:

```
maxtemp = dfmax.groupby(dfmax.index.dayofyear).aggregate(max)
```

and from 
    `maxtemp.info()`

I get this :

Int64Index: 366 entries, 1 to 366

I expected 365 entries. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't remember exactly the Pandas' dayofyear, but logically thinking about it... Non-leap years should have days-of-year 0...364. Leap years have 0...365. If you remove Feb 29 (59th day-of-year) without sliding the later dates forward, a leap year will have 0...365 without 59. March 1 is 60th day in leap years, but 59th in non-leap years. So your data should have all the days-of-year, 0...365 (i.e. 366 entries).

Comment: Thanks Amadan, but I removed the leap days before applying the groupby, so I can't see why there would be any sliding of the data. The total number of rows in the dfmax dataframe is 4015, i.e. 11*365, so I would expect it to give me 365 rows with dayofyear.

Comment: You have 11*365 rows, but 366 different values in them. Jan 1 => 0, Feb 28 => 58, Feb 29 of leap => 59, Mar 1 of non-leap => 59, Mar 1 of leap => 60, Dec 31 of non-leap => 364, Dec 31 of leap => 365. If you want to have 365 different values, you need to subtract 1 from all dates after Feb 29 in leap years, which you say you did not do.

Comment: Just removed the aggregate function and found something interesting, i.e. `maxtemp = dfmax.groupby(dfmax.index.dayofyear)` Looking at the sizes of each row, I get 365 of 11 and the 366th record is 2.  The value in row 366 does not correspond with the highest temp on any of the leap days.  It seems the function adds back the missing leap days?

Comment: Are you sure you get 365 of 11? I think you'll see only 9 at 60th one (`[59]`), not 11.

Comment: Sorry if I'm just being dumb here @Amadan! This is all fairly new for me. There is no index 0 in the dfmax dataframe. It has a datetime index where the first row is 2005-01-01. The maxtemp df starts at 1

Comment: OK, as I said I don't know the details of dayofyear. Just add 1 to each index I've been mentioning. :) the 60th day of the year is either the leap day, or March 1 in non-leap years; if you take away the leap days, if you get two 366s, then you should expect 9 of 60s, not 11.

Comment: @Amadan - just checked and [59] has 11 results. And all the others, except the last one

Comment: 60, if it starts at 1. If all but last have 11, then you mustn't have removed the leap days. But you provide no code, so... it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @Amadan - I can solve the problem by simply dropping the 366th row, but that doesn't really satisfy my need to know :)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Doesn't answer the original question, but does get the desired result `maxtemp = dfmax.groupby([dfmax.index.month, dfmax.index.day]).aggregate(max)
maxtemp.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True) ` .  (found this here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034710/datetime-groupby-resample-month-and-day-across-different-years-drop-the-year]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dayofyear attribute on Pandas maps has nothing to to with what dates actually present in your index. It is an integer assigned according to the position of that day in the calendar.

In other words, December 31 of 2008 is **ALWAYS** 366 regardless of the rest of the index. Therefore, if you are looking at 2008 (leap year) and you remove the last day of Feb, you're only deleting number 60 from the set, not resetting the count.

As per the documentation:

> This attribute returns the day of the year on which the particular
>   date occurs. The return value ranges between 1 to 365 for regular
>   years and 1 to 366 for leap years.