# How to eliminate leap years in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, weather

I have daily temperature data from 1901-1940. I want to exclude leap years i.e. remove any temperature data that falls on 2/29. My data is currently one long array. I am reshaping it so that every year is a row and every column is a day. I'm trying to remove the leap years with the last line of code here:

```
import requests
from datetime import date
params = {"sid": "PHLthr", "sdate":"1900-12-31", "edate":"2020-12-31", "elems": [{"name": "maxt", "interval": "dly",  "duration": "dly", "prec": 6}]}
baseurl = "http://data.rcc-acis.org/StnData"
#get the data
resp = requests.post(baseurl, json=params)
#package into the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'tmax'], data=resp.json()['data'])
#convert the date column to datetimes
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
#select years
mask = (df['date'] >= '1900-01-01') & (df['date'] <= '1940-12-31')
Baseline=df.loc[mask]
#get rid of leap years:
Baseline=Baseline.loc[(Baseline['date'].dt.day!=29) & (Baseline['date'].dt.month!=2)]
```

but when I reshape the array I notice that there are 366 columns instead of 365 so I don't think I'm actually getting rid of february 29th data. How would I completely eliminate any temperature data that is recorded on 2/29 throughout my data set. I only want 365 data points for each year.

```
daily=pd.DataFrame(data={'date':Baseline.date,'tmax':Baseline.tmax})
daily['day']=daily.date.dt.dayofyear
daily['year']=daily.date.dt.year
daily.pivot(index='year', columns='day', values='tmax')
```

Comment: You are getting rid of 2/29 values. `Baseline.loc[(Baseline['date'].dt.day==29) & (Baseline['date'].dt.month==2)]` (listing rows that are on Feb 29) returns results before running your last line; after running your last line, the code snippet I just mentioned returns **nothing**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does pandas dayofyear return 366 rows after I've removed the leap days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393514/why-does-pandas-dayofyear-return-366-rows-after-ive-removed-the-leap-days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of your problem is that you used *daily.date.dt.dayofyear*.

Each day in a year, including *Feb 29* has its own number.

To make thing worse, e.g. *Mar 1* has *dayofyear*:

- 61 in leap years,
- 60 in non-leap years.

One of possible solutions is to set the *day* column to a string
representation of month and day.
To provide proper sort in the pivoted table, the month part should come first.

So, after you convert *date* column to *datetime*, to create both
additional columns run:

```
daily['year'] = daily.date.dt.year
daily['day'] = daily.date.dt.strftime('%m-%d')
```

Then you can filter out *Feb 29* and generate the pivot table in one go:

```
result = daily[daily.day != '02-29'].pivot(index='year', columns='day',
    values='tmax')
```

For some limited source data sample, other than yours, I got:

```
day   02-27  02-28  03-01  03-02
year                            
2020     11     10     14     15
2021     11     21     22     24
```

## An alternative

Create **3** additional columns:

```
daily['year']  = daily.date.dt.year
daily['month'] = daily.date.dt.strftime('%m')
daily['day']   = daily.date.dt.strftime('%d')
```

Note the **string** representation of month and day, to keep leading
zeroes.

Then filter out *Feb 29* and generate the pivot table with a **MulitiIndex**
on columns:

```
result = daily[(daily.month != '02') | (daily.day != '29')].pivot(
    index='year', columns=['month', 'day'], values='tmax')
```

This time the result is:

```
month  02      03    
day    27  28  01  02
year                 
2020   11  10  14  15
2021   11  21  22  24
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to eliminate those items before building the array.

```
import requests
from datetime import date

params = {"sid": "PHLthr", "sdate":"1900-12-31", "edate":"2020-12-31", "elems": [{"name": "maxt", "interval": "dly",  "duration": "dly", "prec": 6}]}
baseurl = "http://data.rcc-acis.org/StnData"
#get the data
resp = requests.post(baseurl, json=params)
vals = resp.json()
rows = [row for row in vals['data'] if '02-29' not in row[0]]
print(rows)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve OP's problem though. They want to "skip" numbering "02-29" in `daily["day"]`

Answer (score 0):

You get 366 columns because of using `dayofyear`. That will calculate the day per the actual calendar (i.e. without removing 29 Feb).

To see this:

```
>>> daily.iloc[1154:1157]

           date       tmax  day  year
1154 1904-02-28  38.000000   59  1904
1156 1904-03-01  39.000000   61  1904
1157 1904-03-02  37.000000   62  1904
```

Notice the day goes from 59 to 61 (the 60th day was 29 February 1904).